# Which one is the healthiest to operate a lantern with: kerosene, diesel or sunflower oil?

Tags: combustion, toxicity, fuel

Given a lantern (originally made for kerosene) however, I'm looking for the fuel which is the safest for indoor use.

I've already tried different kinds, and found three of them that burn just as nicely: kerosene, diesel and sunflower oil, which means, all of these seem to produce nearly the same light, the same heat, and none of them becomes smoky on a medium flame.

The only differences I experience:

- Kerosene stinks quiet badly, and costs 5-6 times as much as the other two.
- Diesel stinks just a little bit and is pretty cheap.
- Sunflower oil doesn't stink at all and is the cheapest.

So from my experiences, I'd go with sunflower oil.

**But the most important question is, based on which I will decide: Which one produces the least poisoning stuff when burnt? So what might be in the air I can't see and should be afraid of.**

(once again: The lantern is always set to a flame that doesn't produce any visible smoke at all.)

Comment: While I don't doubt your intentions in posting this, we do shy away on this site from providing advice that is (broadly) "medical" in nature, and that includes queries such as yours. You might want to rephrase your query a bit. That said: (a) we cannot comment on anything in the air you need to be afraid of short of an air sample from you; and (b) I would avoid using diesel fuel in a lantern (at all), especially in a place where I'm breathing.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mineral_oil is what you want. It is the undyed, unodorised version of what i think you mean by "kerosene". You have to find out what it is called in your country. It should be rather cheap.

Comment: Karl, thanks for the tip, I didn't know about this kind of oil and it seems very promising based on what I read about it. However, it turns out that for some reason it  is not commercially available in my country in its normal industrial form as a first distillate, only its refined version for medical uses, which is quite expensive unfortunately. But I'm still investigating as it seems the best fuel so far for indoor uses. It's a pity I cannot just buy some to try it out..

Comment: If you forget to ventilate your room, all three will kill you after approximately the same time due to lack of oxygen.

Comment: @Jan [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerosene_lamp) cites a source suggesting that a 37-lumen kerosene lantern burns about 25 ml/hour or about 20g/hour. [My answer here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/94827/5387) suggests that this would consume about 68 g of oxygen per hour, which is pretty small -- more than you'd use at rest, but definitely less than while exercising. So you should be fine, unless your house is literally sealed so tightly you can't have company over without asphyxiation. (I still recommend good ventilation, with or without a lantern.)