# What is the IUPAC name of kerosene?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

Is there a standard chemical name for kerosene? Would IUPAC define a name or terminology for it?

Comment: Kerosene is a mixture thus does not have an IUPAC name

Comment: What does “IUPAC supported” mean?

Comment: @JavaScriptCoder iupac affirmed

Comment: No I mean, what does “IUPAC affirmed” mean?

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/94824/what-is-the-empirical-formula-for-kerosene

Comment: @JavaScriptCoder https://iupac.org/what-we-do/recommendations/

Answer (score 8):

Kerosine is not a pure compound so dosen't have a standard IUPAC name. In fact the composition will vary depending on the source.

The major components are long chain (~10-16 carbon) branched and straights chain alkanes plus a mixture of cyclic alkanes and some aromatic alkybenzenes plus naphthalenes. The common factor is they all boil between ~150 °C and 275 °C (which is how they are separated from other components of crude oil).

So, no standard name just a range of varying compositions.